# Prevent App Crashes HRESULT

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a big problem that I hope get help from you. I have a **_RecordsetPtr** variable called **pRstEmployDB**. In my code I have a line to open the Recordset

```
pRstEmployDB->Open("SOCIETE", _variant_t((IDispatch *) theApp.pConEmployDB, true),  adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTable);
```

the problem is when this function crashes (Acces Violation) it shows a messageBox to say that an error happened and crashes. How could I Catch the error so the program will no longer crashes and be closed?

I tried to use ASSERT(... ==S_OK) but crashes too.

I tried this way too, but no hope

```
Try
{
 pRstEmployDB->Open("SOCIETE", _variant_t((IDispatch *) theApp.pConEmployDB, true),   adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTable);
}
catch (CException* e)
{
  return FALSE;
}
```

For Info : The Code of Open function.(msdao15.tli)

```
inline HRESULT Recordset15::Open ( const _variant_t & Source, const _variant_t & ActiveConnection, enum CursorTypeEnum CursorType, enum LockTypeEnum LockType, long Options ) {
    HRESULT _hr = raw_Open(Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a generic catch block?

Comment: Your error handling is all wrong.  Some odds that the connection object is junk because of it.  At least work from the MSDN sample code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx